# template types in a container class

Tags: c++, templates, stdmap

I writing an "Effect" class (for an opengl program) and I'm also attempting to write a container class for.

The Effect class is defined as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class Effect
{
  private:
  Vbo<T>  m_Vbo;
};
```

Where T is a type that describes the vertex attributes.

In order to write a container class, I'd like to store these effects in an std::map:

```
class EffectMgr : public Singleton <EffectMgr>
{
private:
    typedef std::map<std::string, Effect<T> & > EffectMap;
};
```

The error I get with the container class is that T is undefined.  Can someone enlighten me?

I may have (by sheer chance and tinkering) have found the answer although I won't know until I've written the container class:

```
class EffectMgr : public Singleton <EffectMgr>,
{
private:
    template <typename T> 
    typedef std::map<std::string, Effect<T> & > EffectMap;
};
```

Comment: Your first container code is a typedef, the second is not?

Comment: the second is not, but, it was the only syntax that VS2010 would allow, I was just experimenting...

Comment: Templates aren't types; they're templates. Think of templates as code generation tools. You can only program with actual *types*, which is what you get when you *instantiate* a template. There is no relation between `Foo<T>` and `Foo<S>`; they're entirely different, unrelated types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`T` is scoped within the Effect definition. Outside of the scope `T` is undefined.

Perhaps you mean this?

```
template <typename T>
class EffectMgr : public Singleton <EffectMgr>
{
private:
    typedef std::map<std::string, Effect<T> & > EffectMap;
};
// use: EffectMgr<type>::EffectMap
```

If you want only the typedef to be templated then do this:

```
class EffectMgr : public Singleton <EffectMgr>
{
private:
    template <typename T>
    using EffectMap = std::map<std::string, Effect<T> & >; // C++11 feature
};
// use: EffectMgr::EffectMap<type>
```

Comment: Interesting syntax.  I must look into this.  Thanks.

Comment: VS2010 doesn't seem to like this syntax, highlights the using keyword and help says "Error: expected a ;"

Answer (score 0):

Since `Effect` is a template class, and you're not specializing it inside `EffectMgr`, it also needs to be a template:

```
template<typename T>
class EffectMgr : public Singleton <EffectMgr>
{
private:
    typedef std::map<std::string, Effect<T> & > EffectMap;
};
```

Comment: Once I've given it a try, I'll award the answer to you.  Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: this turned out not to be what I'm after :S

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to store effects with a different `T`-ypes in a map.

If it is, the simplest way would be specify interface

```
class IEffect
{
public:
   virtual ~IEffect() = 0;
}

IEffect::~IEffect()
{
}
```

and implement it in your template:

```
template <typename T>
class Effect: public IEffect
{
  private:
  Vbo<T>  m_Vbo;
};
```

now, you can create `std::map<std::string, IEffect* >`

With additional effort, you can write a wrapper over `IEffect` to get rid of pointers.